Updating a SAS table dynamically as new records come in
I'm not very familiar with hashes in SAS and need help updating a table dynamically as new rows come in.
Lets say there is a crosswalk table
Crosswalk



ID
Family




AAA
AAA


BBB
AAA


CCC
AAA


ZZZ
XYY


QQQ
LLL



As new rows come in I need to update their family and add them to the crosswalk table. Consider two new records
New Records



ID
Family




DDD
CCC


EEE
DDD



I need to update these records, such that since DDD is related to CCC and CCC is related to AAA, DDD is related to AAA.
The updated crosswalk would be:
Updated crosswalk



ID
Family




AAA
AAA


BBB
AAA


CCC
AAA


ZZZ
XYY


QQQ
LLL


DDD
AAA


EEE
AAA



Is there any way to achieve this using hash tables? As I can get new records on an hourly or daily basis, I wanted to update the Family only on the new records, and leave the existing records as is.

Do you need to guard against NEW records that would redefine the family of an existing ID? (For Example BBB->ZZZ or BBB->RRR)  What of NEW policy do you want if family can change?

is it some confuse why family and Id have same values ?

Try this
data crosswalk;
input ID $ Family $;
datalines;
AAA AAA 
BBB AAA 
CCC AAA 
ZZZ XYY 
QQQ LLL 
;

data new;
input ID $ Family $;
datalines;
DDD CCC 
EEE DDD 
;

data want(drop = f);

   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      dcl hash h(dataset : 'crosswalk(rename = Family = f');
      h.definekey('ID');
      h.definedata('f');
      h.definedone();
   end;

   set crosswalk new (in = n);

   length f $20;
   f = '';

   h.ref(key : ID, data : Family);
   
   if n then do while (h.find(key : Family) = 0);
      if Family = f then leave;
      Family = f;
   end;

run;

Result:
ID   Family
AAA  AAA
BBB  AAA
CCC  AAA
ZZZ  XYY
QQQ  LLL
DDD  AAA
EEE  AAA

